# Type mismatch error when adding decimals to a variable "vSum"

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Calc()

Dim vSum As Single
Dim lRow As Integer

lRow = Sheet1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

vSum = 0: c = 0
Range("Z2").EntireColumn.ClearContents

For j = 2 To lRow Step 10
    If Cells(j, 3).Value <> 0 Then
        vSum = vSum + Cells(j, 3)
            c = c + 1
        Range("Z" & c + 1).Value = Cells(j, 3)
    End If
Next j

Range("AB2").Value = Format(vSum / c, "00.00")
Range("AB5").Value = c

Call StDev

End Sub
```

The purpose is to find the average.  I know there is an easier way but I want to understand the error.

Comment: Which line causes the error? There are a number of places you could encounter that. For starters, you should declare the row variable as a `Long` not an `Integer`.

Comment: I think this will only happen when contents of `(Cellsj, 3)` cant be cast to a number. Typically when the value is a string or an error - debug.print Cells(j, 3) and see what input value causes it to fail

Comment: If there are only numbers in the analyzed range, they maybe are wrongly formatted. In such a situation, you can try `vSum = vSum + cDbl(Cells(j, 3))`

Comment: the error occurs at vsum = vsum + cells(j,3) incidently at a value of 12622.3.  JohnnieL you are correct in that one of the data numbers was actually a string ie 86.o.  Great information and thank you to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Value` of a cell is its content - not its numerical value. So if you have a string in that cell, you will get the string.

The check `If Cells(j, 3).Value <> 0 Then` will compare the content of the cell with the number 0. Any content of the cell except 0 (and an empty cell) will return `True`, including the mentioned strings. But `vSum` is a number and if the cell contains as string, this will give you a Type mismatch.

Easiest way is to use the `isNumeric`-function to check if the cell contains a number and use the `Val`-Function to check if the value is not 0

```
If isNumeric(Cells(j, 3).Value And Val(Cells(j, 3).Value) <> 0 Then
```